# How can I customise flask-admin to add it to a sb-admin themed app

Tags: bootstrap-4, flask-admin

I have an existing application that I want to add flask-admin too and retain the same look and feel in the admin interface.
Ideally I'd have the admin interface retain the side menu from the bootstrap4 theme I am using (sb-admin-2). However, I can't figure out how to do that.

I would at least like to format the page a little nicer so looking at the flask-admin documentation there is this sentence:

```
Customize the look by specifying a Bootswatch theme that suits your needs (see http://bootswatch.com/3/ for available swatches).
```

But no information on how to do this. Can someone point me in the right direction to either embed the admin pages in my current app (preferable) which is just a bootstrap4 theme, or add some other custom theme from bootswatch?

I tried creating a html file in templates/admin to override master.html with this to no effect:

```
{% extends admin_base_template %}

{% block head_css %}
  {{ super() }}
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="{{ url_for('static', filename='css/sb-admin-2.css') }}">
{% endblock %}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To use a Bootswatch theme do the following:

In your configuration file set the following:

```
# Fluid layout True or False
FLASK_ADMIN_FLUID_LAYOUT = True
# Set the theme name
FLASK_ADMIN_SWATCH = 'flatly'
```

In your static folder create the following directory structure noting how the theme name is used, in this instance the *'flatly'* theme:

```
bootstrap/bootstrap4/swatch/flatly/bootstrap.min.css
```

For Bootstrap 3 use the following directory structure:

```
bootstrap/bootstrap3/swatch/flatly/bootstrap.min.css
```